# Cutting out most of a sink cabinet back panel to access utilities

Tags: cabinets

I am curious if there is any reason NOT TO cut out most of a sink cabinet back panel to have easy access to utilities (*pipes + electrical*) vs tedious stencil gauging where to cut exact holes like you would do with drywall.

Does that 1/8" (*or so*) panel serve any purpose other than cosmetic?

I was thinking to spare myself the trouble of stenciling where the holes are by just cutting out approx. 50% of it in a rectangle and then maybe fill the gap around the perimeter with smart foam or something for draft and rodent protection.

Is there any advantage to taking the extra effort to leave most of it by cutting holes in precise positions?

Answer (score 7):

If it is only 1/8" and there are some structural pieces (typically near the top and bottom) across the back then the panel is not structural and can be removed. In fact, many times the back panel won't even be installed on a sink cabinet. However, if there are no other structural cross pieces on the back then, depending on how well the cabinet is built, how it is attached to the wall, type of countertop, etc., the panel may be important in keeping the cabinet straight.

The only concern I would have is the increased possibility of unwanted cold air or critters coming in, particularly if this is against an outer wall.

Comment: It is against an outer wall but there is drywall, 2x4, insulation and masonry outside. I was also thinking of putting foam around the perimeter of the cut out

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate  That may be true before the cabinet is installed  but after it is secured in place (properly) the back panel has little, if any, racking prevention benefit.

Answer (score 5):

I have always cut out bigger separate sections than what I needed but not the whole back.  Especially for the plumbing.. you don't want to drill  5/8" holes for 1/2" pipes and then have to sweat the shutoff valves while laying down in the cabinets and scorching the back of the cabinet just so you have a tight fit. Same with electric and drain pipes, leave enough space so you can work on them in it future if needed. Trying to cut out part of the cabinet later on for fixing something is a real job.

Comment: Agreed, Jack.   In a previous life, when I was going to college, I worked in a hardware store and did a lot of kitchen cabinet layouts. We had something available called "sink fronts" that were basically just the front and bottom of a cabinet....no sides or back. Whenever I've done a kitchen or bathroom re-model I cut out a big chunk of the back of the cabinet, no issues, even on stand alone vanities. They are usually pretty well anchored to the wall, so racking wasn't an issue.   Yeah, make it easy on yourself and cut out a large portion for access to utilities.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson Interesting. My experience (primarily my own kitchen ~ 21 years ago) is that "sink front" was the term for the fake drawer-front on a sink cabinet. The sink cabinet was (and still is in my kitchen) a full cabinet in all respects (side, base, back, doors) except that instead of drawer slides and a drawer, the top section just has the sink front across it.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact  Could be, I did a quick search (which I should have done before my previous comment), and it seems they ones I was thinking of are quite rare now. The ones I sold when working hardware just had the front, with a door (or 2 depending on the size) and the base.  But dang, that was 45 years ago!  Man how time flies.

Comment: Don't cut any structural pieces, and try to leave at least 4 inches all the way around.

Answer (score -1):

What you’re proposing is a long lasting sign of a rushed job and does not look like quality work. Take the extra time to measure and cut out as little as possible around each piece of plumbing. Install correctly so that every time you or anyone sees under the sink there is not an eyesore.

Comment: The question wasn't "should I?", but "can I?". The disregard for aesthetic outcome is implied in the question. Please take the [tour] to learn how we're different from a discussion forum.

Comment: No one cares what the underside of the sink cabinet looks like. That's why most people cram it full of random utility chemicals and other stuff, garbage bags, etc.

Comment: @kreemoweet, I completely disagree (and I agree with this answer), but that isn't what was asked. You're errantly projecting your opinion on everyone else. Many of us care what the inside of things look like whether anyone sees them or not.